# Replacing nextSibling with other string

Tags: javascript, jquery, nextsibling

I have the following span element:

```
<div class="text" contenteditable="true" id="example">
   <div class="outside">Type here <span class="inside"> please</span>.</div>
   <div class="outside">Name here <span class="inside"> first </span>name</div>
</div>
```

Using the following js function, I can get the length of in between `</span>` and `</div>`:

```
$('span.inside').each(function() {               
    var sphs = $(this).get(0).nextSibling;
    var len = sphs.length;

    //If the length is less than 2
    if(len < 2){
        // i want to replace it with another words like "thanks."   

       }
 })
```

If the length is less than 8, then I want to replace it with another words or strings ( for example, `thanks.`) IN BETWEEN `</span>` and `</div>` (see the word "thanks" placement).

```
<div class="text" contenteditable="true" id="example">
   <div class="outside">Type here <span class="inside"> please</span>thanks.</div>
</div>
```

How would I replace it with another string?

**EDIT:**

Note that I am using `.each` as there could be multiple span element with the same class name. In the first line, there is only a period (`</span>.</div>`), thus it satisfies the condition and will be replaced with another word (in this case "thanks").

In the second line (`</span>name</div>`), the length is larger than 2, thus it won't get replaced.

I hope this clarifies it.

```
<div class="text" contenteditable="true" id="example">
   <div class="outside">Type here <span class="inside"> please</span>.</div>
   <div class="outside">Name here <span class="inside"> first </span>name</div>
</div>
```

...will become...

```
<div class="text" contenteditable="true" id="example">
   <div class="outside">Type here <span class="inside"> please</span> thanks.</div>
   <div class="outside">Name here <span class="inside"> first </span>name</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('span.inside').length;` is the length of the jQuery object (so here always 1), not the length of the contents!

Comment: @cFreed I am aware of that. haha. Please look bit below `var len = sphs.length;`.

Comment: Oh, ok. Didn't pay attention enough.

Comment: =) No worries. I guess the first portion wasn't necessary in this question. I am going to edit it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('span.inside').each(function() {               
    var sphs = $(this).get(0).nextSibling;
    var len = sphs.length;

    //If the length is less than 2
    if(len < 2){
        // DOM method:
        sphs.textContent = ' Thanks.';
        // jQuery method:
        $(this).parent().get(0).childNodes[2].textContent = ' Thanks.';
    }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text" contenteditable="true" id="example">
   <div class="outside">Type here <span class="inside"> please</span>.</div>
   <div class="outside">Type here <span class="inside"> please</span> ok?</div>
</div>
```

Or try here
https://jsfiddle.net/8pa4akzh/3/

Comment: This affects the `outside` element. I am trying to replace "`</span>.</div>`" with `</span>Thanks</div>`.

Comment: Got it, check now

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate it! :)

Comment: More simply: `sphs.textContent = ' Thanks.';

Comment: Updated, Thanks cFreed

Comment: Why `$(this).get(0).nextSibling` and not `this.nextSibling`?

Comment: David Thomas, this part of code is not mine, I didn't changed it to be more recognizable clear for the author

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra (empty) span and set it. It's as simple as setting the [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) of the span.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="text" contenteditable="true" id="example">
    <div class="outside">Type here <span class="inside"> please</span><span id="extra"></span></div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
   //If the length is less than 2
   if(len < 2){
        $('span#extra').text("thanks.");
   }
```

Comment: This is inside of span element. I am trying to replace the word that is outside of the span element (in between `</span>` and `</div>`.

Comment: @steveKim Are you looking to remove any text like the " please" or are you just trying to append "thanks."?

Comment: In this example, "please" is inside of the span. I am trying to add "Thanks." just outside of the span (but has to be in between '</span>` and `</div>`. Thus, anything inside of span will be untouched.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Adding another element in between will make the code alot more complicated. Thus, I am trying to avoid it. I mean, I can use `substr` to just replace the whole thing. But I wanted to see if there was an easier way to just simply target the nextSibling area.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. To make things even more complicated, there are multiple span elements inside with the same class name (Thus the usage of `.each`). The `.parent()` won't be an effective way. I will update the question to clarify,